# 2-step authentication to Gmail from Azure App service

Tags: azure, spring-boot, gmail, azure-web-app-service, email-verification

I have a Spring boot application run on Azure App Service, from which I want to send emails to users.

I can already do that with a gmail account I created myself, I just needed to turn on "allow less secure apps" feature.

However, I'm required to use another gmail account which belongs to a organization and thus is forced to use 2-step verification as per the organization policy.

Is it possible to complete the 2-step verification process from Azure's App service? What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to complete the 2-step verification process from Azure's App service?

**In short**, we **couldn't** do that from Azure's App service directly with you gmail account.
From [goolge document](https://support.google.com/a/answer/175197#setup) we could know
that 2-Step Verification adds an extra layer of security to your users' managed Google accounts by requiring them to enter a verification code in addition to their username and password when signing in to their account.

In your case, according to your organization policy the google account is forced to enable 2-Step Verification. Based on my understanding, we can't do from the Azure's App service directly.

> What other options do I have?

Based on my experince, you could registry a SendGrid account with your organization gmail account. Then you could use sendgrid to send the email to other users. Then other users could get the email from the organization gmail account but maybe there is no sent mails in the organization gmail account. More detail please refer to [How to Send Email Using SendGrid with Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email).

**Note: I don't test it on my side.**